Spaceships for froglike aliens
My intelligent alien species, the Broaste, have reached Kardashev II. They are intelligent frogs whose physiology is very much like that of frogs on Earth - they have opposable thumbs and can walk bipedally, but get around largely through jumping, need water to spawn in, etc. I'm currently trying to describe the interior of a spaceship (most environmentally damaging heavy industry is done away from their homeworld through eg asteroid mining and so on).  Most homes and transport are designed with either water channels or separate compartments for tadpoles while they still cannot breathe air. My question is - what would their spaceship look like inside? I'm thinking of a pressurised cabin and water underneath a porous floor so that it didn't slosh about too much, but would this be correct? As they don't need to be in water constantly, I've made the spaceship damp rather than fill it with water, but is there anything else I need to think about?

Not an answer, but random thought; water in spaceship is a super interesting idea. In fiction, I've read about it being used to turn space-ship into battering ram, as water can only compress so much, add way more mass than air and thus has way higher inertia. So having submerged sections of the ship is definitely going to be a technical complication.
Also, if not everything is filled with water, it will logically try to flow towards the "bottom" (e.g. opposite to your acceleration in space).
So, frame challenge, but do you need the tadpoles in space? What for? Are those Generation ships?

I don't need the tadpoles in space, but if, for example, they are travelling with their parents to visit a relative who is working off world. I thought of maybe having shallow channels under the floor.

This stack is finally going to design something wholesome, my heart is filled with joy for the little tadpoles visiting grandma two planets over.

Aw thanks!! Yeah, I've had this story in my head a long time and want to do the best possible job and also get it as scientifically accurate as I could (some of the elements anyway).

Hi @RachaelHorwitz, welcome to [worldbuilding.se]. We're happy to help you build your space ship, but you've ask a question that's too broad. Should we focus on the bridge? Living compartments? Engineering? Should we focus on zero-g in water, containment of the water, what happens during acceleration? Should we focus on water recycling and pressure? When you ask a question, it needs to be geared toward one-specific-question/one-best-answer. Could you [edit] your post to focus on just one problem? It's OK to ask several questions, though we suspect you'll see where we're going after a couple.

Oh, one more thing, I assume by "what would their ship look like" you mean the interior, not the exterior. The exterior is anything you want it to be as it's just a shell holding everything else together. Long, short, round, square, distributed, centralized... it's pretty much just an aesthetic that's only an issue if you intend to take it into an atmosphere - in which case the nature of your creatures is irrelevant.

Yes I was trying to describe the interior. :)

@Nyakouai Wait, you don't want us to un-burninate the torture tag? (/s)

OK I have edited it a bit.

Now for story purposes I'm not going to be saying anything particularly useful here, but when going for pure realism I find it nearly impossible to imagine a type 2 civilization that hasn't moved beyond the limitations of paltry animals. They'll be long past the point of merging biology and technology, to the point where the only physical limitations (such as needing a wet environment) they have will be ones they want to have.

Do you have artificial gravity available for those froggers? It would be a completely different design depending on that answer.

We're not here to build spaceships for you or tell you what things to consider in your fictional world. Is there a specific problem you are having?ask us for help with that.

@rachaelhorwitz Thanks for the edits, it's a better first quesiton. When you get time, please read through the [tour], [help/on-topic], [help/dont-ask] and [ask]. Stack Exchange has more rules than your average forum and as you gain experiene with the site you'll be held to the rules more. Thanks.

Thanks for letting me know. Thanks for the answers, this is all really helpful  :)

Look at Larry Niven & Jerry Pournelle's "Footfall". The aliens look like twin/bifurcated trunk baby elephants but are highl;y intelligent. They relax in communal mudrooms. Many of their reflex actions/thoughts are based on an elephant like pre-history. Not overly close to your frogs BUT shows how alienness invades the mindset of space going weapon using intelligent creatures.

I think you need to readjust how you think about a K2 civilization.
Like, at this this "power level", they have enough energy and engineering chops to make the spaceships and their bodies be essentially whatever they want them to be.
If they are traditionalists, then there is no reason they can't simply make the inhabited section of the spaceship into an indistinguishable replica of their perfect habitat (artificial gravity, atmosphere, lighting, etc).
If they don't care about tradition or are more "minimalist", then there are solutions like suspended animation for long spaceflight trips, or just re-engineering themselves on a genetic level to be more compatible with spaceflight. Air pressure, gravity, a wet environment, etc these are just engineering challenges that a K2 civ should be able to design their way around. They could just design themselves to be perfectly vacuum-adapted, including their young, and done.
The considerations you raise in your question seem to me to be more in-line with thoughts that a <= K1 civ needs to deal with, where building something like an artificial gravity system might be a significant challenge and investment, or where they are not already essentially genetic wizards.

Thanks. Yes, they definitely are traditionalists and have tried to keep their planet as 'natural' as possible...

The artificial gravity thing sounds good. I'll look into that :)

"They could just design themselves to be perfectly vacuum-adapted, including their young, and done." - when I read that, the thought crossed my mind of a vacuum-proof frog entering suspended animation and then being launched at relativistic speed to a next star by a cannon. Surely that's not what you meant, but what you wrote doesn't deny it... +1

Frogs on Earth have a lot of variation between species and none of them actually need water quite as much as people tend to think.  Even the most water dependent of the bunch can survive fine out of water for hours at a time, most can survive for days out of it and some can last for years out of water. Even tadpoles of some species are fine out of water for a week.
Maybe the right place to start answering this question would be to step back from the spaceship for a minute and think about how dependent on water you want them to be.  That, and how you want this to impact your story, will really drive your design.
Is their need for water so extreme that they would go through the expense and negative impact on their spaceships to have it freely around their ship or be confined in suits?  Is there some cultural or psychological reason that would require that?  If so there are other answers here that perfectly address that.  If not, would it make more sense for to have them hop into a shower once or twice a day to keep their skin moist?  Could they get around the issue entirely with some salve or gel?  Are they able to stay out of water long enough that they don't really even bother with it on their ships?
There's not really a "it has to be this way" answer to this, which means you can make it be whatever way actually fits into the story you're trying to tell.  There's not really a wrong answer here.

They can survive without water but need a moist environment, more so than what would be found in the average spaceship. That's why I had the idea of the water being contained somewhere. Thanks so much for your reply  :)

Ideally they'd just be up and about at takeoff (maybe) and landing. And even then only some of them. So the interior could be spartan and assigned to instruments rather than comfort with your Space Frogiens in Space suits.
Spaceships could just be life support enclosed units where the Frogiens sleep until they arrive at their destination. Or perhaps the Frogiens have their own mechanism for it. There are desert frogs on Earth that create a membrane around themselves and have a rest for years at a time until the next rain fills their puddle.
There is nothing to see on a Space journey, so the inherent hibernation abilities of frogs would be better suited to space travel than humans who need to eat and exercise all the time.
I'd be a lot more motivated to go on a space journey if I slept through it & I didn't have to twiddle my thumbs in close proximity to a bunch of other people who probably won't like each other much by the time we disembark. Especially if it's for a lengthy period. If it's for centuries I'd much rather that I'm the person who arrives on my adventure. I take the risk, I have the adventure, not force my agenda on my great grandkids and all the descendants in between.

Good point, I was thinking of a relatively fast space journey rather than something taking years, but in some situations they'd definitely hibernate.

@rachaelhorwitz I prefer to sleep through 8 hour flights, I purposely stay up the previous night doing productive things, because there's nothing to do on the flight. How short are your journeys?

Sorry for the delay. I'd say a few weeks or so?

Then same, I'd rather sleep through it. There's nothing to do and nothing to see. Stick me in a cocoon and wake me up when my adventure starts please.

Space suits and aquaria
A space suit is meant to create a homogeneous environment. An environment that should keep the wearer within certain parameters to survive. This can be used in the tadpoles. They will be in a suit with a small layer of water inside and other life support. Probably adding some features to allow growth. If required you can add some motorised support to make the swimming easier. This way tadpoles can move throughout the ship. They are arguably better suited to 0-G, as they can swim in the air in nearly the same way as in water. If you want to make it closer to in water, you can add larger fins to offset the lower viscosity of air.
The suit eliminates three large problems. Water is incredibly heavy, and thus you would prefer to take as little as possible. Having water 'loose' in the cabin can give a whole lot of problems. Rust, bridging electronics, choking hazard and even being dangerous when accelerating/decelerating with a high delta. By putting it in suits you'll contain it. Finally the tadpoles will not be restricted in movement, despite the minimal amount of water present.
Of course, suits do not solve everything. There will still be aquaria with water for changing suits, sleeping quarters and more. These will have 'airlocks' to keep the water at bay. It'll minimise water in the cabin, reducing any negative effects this can have on the ship itself.

Thanks very much! I may have some writing to do but they already have these watery suits so that's a really good point!

Don't forget that in generational ships, there would be living quarters and breeding grounds, simulating the migratory pathways they are used to on the grounds. So a generation-ship would look like a forested meadow, slopping towards a crechee area with ponds.
Food would be served on the fly, as in bred as dense insect swarms - in areas were visibility is allowed to be low. Moisturized drizzle would be everywhere, so all electronics are hardened.
Loud, territorial sounds are heavily discouraged, as they would start a territorial shouting match on the ship.To have a subordinate on your back during the migration season, is considered a sign of fitness by ruling elite.
Traditional there are two types of dangers, those from below and those from above. Above is the danger you expect least, and look out for, so all the monitors are from above. Sensorreports and statusreports come from below, also a source of danger but also a source of quick escape - aka the escapepods.
Cold saps your activity, so the whole ship is heated. Cryosleep is the whole ship going into hibernation at the same time. Messages are transported by small robotic dragonflies. Vision is peripheral, focused to take in most of the surroundings in 3d, thus screens are wrap around affairs.
Nations are a strange concept, what is more familiar, is pond groups and families.

Thanks - they don't really have generational ships but they used to and that will be really useful in filling in the backstory
